# How to Auto Logout a user to login page after session is over in Java Web Application?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, stripes

Requirement is If  user session gets invalidated it should automatically redirect user to login page without making any server call. Solution with calling server on regular interval doesn't fit as it increase server load.

Answer (score 2):

I got your point, you don't want to make any extra call for managing session, in fact it is a good question.

Either it may be simple servlet, spring-mvc or spring-security  auto logout is not possible without perfect client side logic.
Considering application will have both type of request

- AJAX and
- form submission/page reload

Auto logout needs very calculated logic. Presenting my autologout functionality implementation with following

### Advantages.

---

1. No extra call/request is used to achieve this. considering performance impact if more than 10k active users and extra calls to achieve auto logout.
2. One line configuration using  tag.
3. Works flawlessly even if user opens multiple tab or multiple window.
4. It intimates you before 30 seconds of session invalidation, so if you have filled form and not submitted, you can keep session alive(extend session by one click). So user less likely to loose unsaved data.

### Usage

---

**1. Include auto logout script in required JSP pages as given below.**

```html
    ....
    </body>
    <jsp:include page="../template/autologout-script.jsp"></jsp:include>
</html>
```

**2. Create a JSP page, autologout-script.jsp and add below code.**
Note: No  editing/configuring is required

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var timeOutTimeInSeconds = ${ timeOutTimeInSeconds }; 
    var showTimerTimeInSeconds= ${ showTimerTimeInSeconds };

    var sessionCheckIntervalId = setInterval(redirectToLoginPage, timeOutTimeInSeconds * 1000);
    var timerDisplayIntervalId = setInterval(showTimer, (timeOutTimeInSeconds - showTimerTimeInSeconds) * 1000);
    var badgeTimerId;
    window.localStorage.setItem("AjaxRequestFired", new Date());

    function redirectToLoginPage(){
        //location.href =  '<c:url value="/" />'+'${loginPageUrl}';
        window.location.reload();
    }

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        resetTimer();
    });

    $(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
         if(e.originalEvent.key == "AjaxRequestFired"){
             console.log("Request sent from another tab, hence resetting timer")
             resetTimer();
         }
    });

    function resetTimer()
    {
        showTimerTimeInSeconds= ${ showTimerTimeInSeconds };

        console.log("timeOutTimeInSeconds : "+timeOutTimeInSeconds)
        window.localStorage.setItem("AjaxRequestFired", new Date());

        window.clearInterval(sessionCheckIntervalId);
        sessionCheckIntervalId = setInterval(redirectToLoginPage, timeOutTimeInSeconds * 1000);

        window.clearInterval(timerDisplayIntervalId);
        timerDisplayIntervalId = setInterval(showTimer, (timeOutTimeInSeconds - showTimerTimeInSeconds) * 1000);

        hideTimer();
    }

    function showTimer()
    {
        $('#sessionTimeRemaining').show();
        $('#sessionTimeRemainingBadge').html(showTimerTimeInSeconds--);
        window.clearInterval(timerDisplayIntervalId);
        badgeTimerId = setInterval(function(){
            $('#sessionTimeRemainingBadge').html(showTimerTimeInSeconds--);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function hideTimer()
    {
        window.clearInterval(badgeTimerId);
        $('#sessionTimeRemaining').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

**3. Configure session attributes to configuring timeout setting**
Note: Configure this after session creation. You can implement HttpSessionListener sessionCreated method and set the following configuration as per your requirement.

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);

session.setAttribute("timeOutTimeInSeconds", 300);
session.setAttribute("showTimerTimeInSeconds", 30);
```

**4. Add below html for displaying timer.**
Note: it can be moved to autologout-script template page if you are good at CSS. Hence you can avoid to add this in each and every page.
Include bootstrap or add your custom css.

```
<span class="badge badge-primary" title="click to keep session alive" id="sessionTimeRemaining" 
    onclick="ajaxSessionRefresh()" style="display:none;">
    <i class="badge badge-danger" id="sessionTimeRemainingBadge" style="float:left">30</i>
     &nbsp; 
     <small>Refresh</small>
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</span>
```

[image]

That is all about a simple auto logout implementation.
You can download working example from my github repository
[Autologout using simple servlet example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/servletproject-autologout)
[Autologout using spring-security java configuration example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-autologout-javaconfig)
[Autologout using spring-security xml configuration example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-autologout-xmlconfig)

### Logic Explained

---

**Case 1: On Page load**
Here logic is simple, on page load set timer of interval equlas to maxInactiveInterval. after timeout redirect to login page.
**Case 2: Keep track AJAX calls**
Now considering AJAX requests, you can use .ajaxStart() or .ajaxComplete() callbacks of jquery so that if any ajax request is fired you can reset the interval.
**Case 3: Tracking multi tab/window activity**
Intertab communication is done to synchronize state of each tab. Used localStorage on change event.

*Limitations/Improvements required*
1. If maximum allowed session is one, if session is taken from another system, AJAX request will fail. It needs to be handled to redirect to login page.
2. Use ajaxStart() instead of ajaxComplete() to have exact sync of idleTime values between server and browser.

*Requirements*
1. Jquery

## Alternatives to current implementation compared

---

1. **Setting Refresh header** in http response. *(Not works for AJAX requests)*

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "60; URL=login.jsp");
```

2. **Setting meta refresh tag** in HTML *(Not works for AJAX requests)*

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=login.jsp">
```

3. **Configuring Activity checker**
   Keeps session alive by repeated AJAX request. Tracks idle time and makes logout request after timeout.
   No doubt it is a good one with simple logic. But i want to just ink my observations.

   - **Performance impact** if 2 requests are made per minute to keep session alive and 50k active users. 100k requests per minute.
   - **Intertab communication** If two tabs are open, one tab is receiving activity but other tab is not receiving activity, that tab fires logout request and invalidate session even though activity is present in other tab. (But can be handled)
   - **Force logout approach** It is a client is dominated over server to invalidate session.

Answer (score 0):

What about writing a servlet filter? If client send new request to server he will be redirected to login page. 
Here's example:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);//false means: don't create if it doesn't exist
        if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");//your login page
        }
}
```

Comment: Sending a request to server is not feasible in my case.

Comment: @ManojKumar, If user can't send a request to server, then how will he use your application?